# Getting this error: ERROR! 'openssl_certificate' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ssl, ansible, yaml, ssl-certificate

So I'm trying to run a little playbook to test out the openssl_certificate module documented here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/openssl_certificate_module.html

My playbook:

```
---
- name: play to run opensll verification
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
- name: Running OpenSSL Module.
  openssl_certificate:
    path: "bleh.crt"
    provider: assertonly
    valid_in: "{{ (20*3600*24) | int }}"
  register: VALIDATION_OUTPUT
  ignore_errors: true
```

Basically I wanna see if the cert is valid in the given time frame. However, when I run

```
ansible-playbook openssl_test.yml
```

I get:

```
ERROR! 'openssl_certificate' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/path/to/my/yaml/openssl_test.yml': line 6, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
- name: Running OpenSSL Module.
  ^ here
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something small.

Comment: You have the indentation wrong; it should be under `tasks:` but you have it as a top level list item, and top level items in playbooks are Plays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. while copying the yaml data, you may use `:set paste` if using `vim` editor to persevere the indentation.

```
---
- name: play to run opensll verification
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Running OpenSSL Module.
    openssl_certificate:
      path: "bleh.crt"
      provider: assertonly
      valid_in: "{{ (20*3600*24) | int }}"
    register: VALIDATION_OUTPUT
    ignore_errors: true
```